# Self-transparent object only looks correct from one side

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, 3d, three.js, webgl

I am using THREE.js with the WebGL renderer and I have a self-transparent object. It's a mesh of a single geometry with a basic material having a texture and `transparent: true`. It looks right from one side, where transparent parts of itself layer correctly, but not from the other:

[image]

The trees on the left look wrong (the map behind them is ignored) while the trees on the right are fine (the map behind them can be seen through). The entire thing you see is a single geometry.

Any ideas how to fix this?

I am currently using a kludge solution of making each transparent face its own object, but this is not ideal.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what your are doing, and without code, it is difficult to help you. As a guess, in the single-geometry case, try `material.alphaTest = 0.5`. If that does not work, can you provide relevant code, and a _simple_ fiddle or live example to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I'd make a fiddle, but jsFiddle doesn't provide anyway to add textures. Also, I highly suspect I know what the issue is (faces within a single geometry cannot be depth-sorted) and that it is indeed a WebGL/OpenGL issue, not a THREE.js-specific issue as you've assumed.

Comment: I think you are running over the [same issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5189) as I did. Unfortunately I couldn't find any solution except of splitting the single mesh into multiple objects and setting the ```renderDepth```.

Answer (score 2):

I once had the same problem.

Here is a nice Video for you to understand why this happens:

[Udacity Classroom Course](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs291/l-91376562/m-103530766)

Check out renderer.sortObjects and object.Model.material.depthWrite, they can help you but it's hard to fix it 100% correctly. It will cost a lot of GPU, can you upload your Code to Codepen, pastebin, dropbox or anything (only the necessary stuff) so I can try to fix it for you.

**EDIT:**
Maybe first try to set all the transparent Meshes to:

```
object.Model.material.depthWrite = false;
```

**EDIT2:** 
Just try the depthWrite = false on the Transparent Objects!

Comment: I've tried `depthWrite = false;` before, but that doesn't really work. It completely screws up the rendering of the object.

Comment: The Udacity course was informative, however. I guess I'll just have to stick with the kludge.

Comment: Did you used renderer.sortObjects = false; too when you used depthWrite = false; ?

Comment: The result of doing that looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/9yclI3N.png (which is what `depthWrite = false;` without `sortObjects = false;` looked like before)

Comment: That's strange. Okay I don't can tell you how this happens to your stuff. Maybe you have to specify for each Object the renderDepth. But I think this isn't a good way. I rebuild your scene and try to help you.